# OpenShift :: How do we enable traffic into pod on a custom port (non-web / non-http)

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, openshift-enterprise

How do we enable traffic into pod on a custom port (non-web / non-http).

For example consider the port 12121.

I tried exposing the port through route. 
But could not reach this pod from another pod within the same namespace.

Is this feature supported in OpenShift ?

If anybody has tried this before, please share how you managed to achieve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? If so can you please tell us what you did? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You have a few options depending on what you are trying to achieve but I wouldn't use a Route for this.

- If you do not care about what the port number is then you can use a **NodePort** service. NodePorts are a range of ports defined by the cluster administrator (default is 30000-32767) that can be assigned to a service and are exposed on every node in the cluster and it works for TCP and UDP traffic. This example specifies a NodePort to use but if you do not give one, the service controller will assign one that is available.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    name: mysql
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      nodePort: 30306
      name: http
  selector:
    name: mysql
```

OpenShift documentation: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_nodeport.html

If you need to expose a specific port then you can:

- Use a **LoadBalancer** service which will allow you to expose a port on the load balancer IP. Note that this requires the cluster being set up with a list of IPs that can be used (this is configuration on the master) AND the IPs are routed to nodes in the cluster (this can be achieved with OpenShift's ipfailover automation).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: egress-2 
spec:
  ports:
  - name: db
    port: 3306 
  loadBalancerIP:
  type: LoadBalancer 
  selector:
    name: mysql
```

OpenShift documentation: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_load_balancer.html

- Less ideally, you could use **hostport** and expose the port directly on the host that the pod is running on but this only works if you want to route traffic to the host with no traffic balancing. This method goes against best practices but can be used as a last resort.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  containers:
  - image: mysql
    name: mysql
    ports:
    - name: mysql
      containerPort: 3306
      hostPort: 3306
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the existing `router` with ports which you want to add, or add the `router` with the customized ports. Refer [Customizing the Router Service Ports](https://docs.okd.io/latest/install_config/router/default_haproxy_router.html#customizing-the-router-service-ports) for details.

- Customizing the Router

```
    oc adm router --replicas=0 --ports='12121:12121,443:443' 
    oc set env dc/router ROUTER_SERVICE_HTTP_PORT=12121  \
                         ROUTER_SERVICE_HTTPS_PORT=443
    oc scale dc/router --replicas=1

    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12121 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did not mean to change the HTTP PORT, I was asking for NON-WEB / NON-HTTP application related query. If you have any suggestion regarding this scenario, please share. Thank you once again.